# jquery how to set different input id of multi field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working add multi field select option field with auto set the unit price when select the item and set the total price with jquery

However it come to a problem when I add other field below, the id of new unit price input and select input wont change 
[image]

```
Item Name
<select id="payselect" name="item_name[]">
<option  data-typeid="<?php echo $row['stock_price']?>" value="<?php echo 
$row['stock_name']?>"><?php echo $row['stock_name']?></option>
</select>

Quantity
<input id="paynumber" name="item_quantity[]" type="number">

Unit Price
<input type="number" name="item_unit[]" id="payunit">

Total Amount
<input type="number" name="sp_price"  id="paytotal" >



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#payselect").on("change", function(){

var price = 0;
var pricenumber=0;
$("#payselect").find("option:selected").each(function(){
price += $(this).data("typeid");
});

$('#paynumber').val(1);
$('#payunit').val(price);

var unitprice= $('#payunit').val();
var unitnumber= $('#paynumber').val();

pricenumber=unitprice*unitnumber;


$("#paytotal").val(pricenumber);

}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of such behaviour is non-closed

```html
<select>
```

tag.
Also I recommend you to use

```html
$(document).ready()
```

before attaching any event handlers.